# Is there an official website to check if Saudi Arabia is member of the United Nations human rights council

Tags: united-nations, human-rights, saudi-arabia

I told someone about Saudi Arabia's membership of the United Nations human rights council. He denied. Is there an **official** website to check if Saudi Arabia is member of the United Nations human rights council?

Comment: On what grounds did he deny it? It's well-known that they headed it at one point. http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/anger-after-saudi-arabia-chosen-to-head-key-un-human-rights-panel-10509716.html

Comment: he is Skeptic. (but he is right to deny in this case; its really a joke/tragedy  that Saudi Arabia is member of the UN human rights council.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the [UN Human Rights Commission](http://www.ohchr.org/EN/HRBodies/HRC/Pages/CurrentMembers.aspx)

> Current Membership of the Human Rights Council, 1 January - 31 December 2016
>
> Saudi Arabia  2016